# How to use libcurl for storing gzip response from REST API?

Tags: c++, libcurl

We have one REST API which returns response in gzip form. Whenever I download that same response from postman and save it as .zip it gets stored correctly. However, when I write the response to .zip file using libcurl methods then file gets corrupted by invalid data. No differences found on comparing the responses from postman and libcurl methods.

```
FILE * wfp1 = SYSS_fopen(responseFile, "w+"); //File pointer to write the REST response
if (!wfp1)
{
    perror("Write File Open:");
}

request.SetWriteDataObject(wfp1);
request.SetWriteDataFn([&](void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    char* fchar = nullptr;
    fchar = static_cast<char*>(contents);
    char* buffer = (char*)SM_alloc(nmemb + 1, sizeof(char));
    snprintf(buffer, nmemb + 1, "%s", fchar);
    fileStream.append(buffer);
    SM_free(buffer);
    return fwrite(contents, size, nmemb, (FILE*)stream);
});
```

Comment: Note that gzip, and zip are different formats.

Comment: Treating a chunk of compressed data like a 0-terminated C style string is probably a Bad Idea...

Comment: in addition to the two previous good remarks; if this is a windows system you might need to open the file as "binary"